Ros2 Gazebo - Import DAE no Texture
I created a map in Blender (with texutures). I exported it as a .dae file and imported it as a model in Gazebo. Even though in blender I added textures, in gazebo everything is a grey mess. Is Gazebo unable to read texture from .dae files?
Thanks!
https://pastebin.com/4j02YHDa


You need to bake the texture maps.
Refer to this previous answer for more detailed information.
